# Explanation of Proof of Theorem 6.1 of Chapter II of The Laplace Transform by Widder

Tags: bounded-variation, moment-problem

> I was reading [The Laplace Transform](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/048647755X) by Widder and have a problem in understanding the proof of theorem 6.1 in chapter II. Please see the following image

[image: Theorem 6.1 Chapter II]

> I am unable to understand how equation 2 becomes equation 4 with the help of equation 3. So my question is how to get equation 4 from equation 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\alpha$ is integrable, $\displaystyle\beta(t) = \int_0^t \alpha(u) \, du$ is of bounded variation and

$$\int_0^1 t^n d \beta(t) = \int_0^1 t^n \alpha(t) \, dt = 0$$

This follows formally by writing $d\beta(t) = \alpha(t) \, dt$. However, a rigorous proof is needed in general, for $\alpha$ not everywhere continuous, and is given  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2562823/148510).

We can now follow the same steps (IBP) leading from (1) to (2) to obtain (4):

$$\int_0^1 t^n \beta(t)\, dt = 0 \quad\quad\quad\quad (n=0,1,2,\ldots) $$