# Domain of Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Region_of_convergence), if the Laplace transform
$$\mathcal{L}\{f\}(s)=\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_0^b e^{-st}f(t)\,dt$$
converges for some $s_0\in\mathbb{R}$, then it automatically converges for all $s\in\mathbb{R}$ with $s>s_0$. (I'm considering the Laplace transform on the real line.) How can I prove this? If
$$\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_0^be^{-st}|f(t)|\,dt$$
converges, then I can prove it using comparison test, but what if it converges conditionally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is essentially @RRL's answer given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4015880), re-written for more novice readers: I worked within real numbers, and also I did not use Riemann-Stieltjes integral.

Let $\alpha:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by
$$\alpha(t)\mathrel{\mathop:}=\int_0^te^{-s_0t}f(t)\,dt.$$
Let $s>s_0$. Since $\alpha$ is continuous, integration by parts gives
\begin{align}\int_0^be^{-st}f(t)\,dt&=\int_0^be^{-(s-s_0)t}e^{-s_0t}f(t)\,dt\\
&=[e^{-(s-s_0)t}\alpha(t)]_0^b+(s-s_0)\int_0^be^{-(s-s_0)t}\alpha(t)\,dt.\tag{$\ast$}\label{lap}
\end{align}
By assumption, $\lim_{t\to\infty}\alpha(t)$ exists. In particular, $|\alpha(t)|$ is bounded, say $|\alpha|\leq M$. Then
$$|e^{-(s-s_0)t}\alpha(t)|\leq e^{-(s-s_0)t}M\quad\xrightarrow{t\to\infty}\quad0,$$
so the first term in \eqref{lap} goes to zero as $b\to\infty$.
On the other hand,
$$\int_0^be^{-(s-s_0)t}|\alpha(t)|\,dt\leq M\int_0^be^{-(s-s_0)t}\,dt\leq M\int_0^\infty e^{-(s-s_0)t}\,dt,$$
so $\int_0^\infty e^{-(s-s_0)t}|\alpha(t)|\,dt$ converges, hence $\int_0^\infty e^{-(s-s_0)t}\alpha(t)\,dt$ converges.
It follows that $\int_0^\infty e^{-st}f(t)\,dt$ converges.